# Disable "Remember my credentials" on Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-registry, group-policy

I would like to disable the ability to save network passwords (when connecting to \computer\share) on Windows 7 Home Premium.

[image: password prompt]

On Windows XP there was a registry setting to disable the checkbox "Save password" for network shares:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Lsa]
"disabledomaincreds"=dword:00000001
```

However on Windows 7 it doesn't work.

[It is written](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj852185.aspx) that you can disable it in GPO in the following place:

```
\Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options
```

However GPO is not available on Home Premium. I know you can hack GPO onto HP, but I would like to have a simple reg setting for this policy.

**Do you know what is the reg value for the above setting?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this is an old question, but I just faced a similar problem. On Windows 7 Pro, you can prevent the credentials from being saved by setting

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ **CurrentControlSet** \Control\Lsa\disabledomaincreds

to 1. Maybe using the setting in ControlSet001 was your issue. However, this won't "disable" the check-box, it will just make it useless.